# Create a block with related content selected from "page" content type

Tags: views

I've two content-types:

'Page' and 'Bike'

From the page, I use a Entity reference field 'field_kies_je_leasefiets', where I link to several bikes.

I want to create a block, placed on the full node view of the 'page', to show a block with 'linked bikes on this page'.

I am struggeling to remember how I used to do this in the past. What 'CONTEXTUAL FILTERS' do I add? I tried 'NID', but that fails. Will someone please be so kind, to give me some pointers?

[image]

[image]
[image]

And this is the solution, given by a user below:

[make relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcWfH.png)
[image: Give a descriptive name]
[image: Apple contextual filter]

Comment: What is a block "with 'linked bikes on this page?"  What are the linked bikes?  The bike content type that is linked on the page?  Or actual links to the bikes?

Comment: Also, how did you configure the NID contextual filter?  Usually in a case like this you can set the option for the NID contextual filter to `Provide default: Content ID from URL`.

Comment: First, thank you very much for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated. 

#1: With Views I output to a block, to be placed on the page. The linked bikes are linked with a entity reference 'field-kies-je-lease-fiets'.

Will add pictures above...

Answer (score 1):

So you need *a list of bikes* that only show the ones *referenced by the current page*. What you'll need to do first is configure that view to list nodes filtered by the Bike type.

Then, in order to filter by the current Page it's on, you need two things:

1. You need to bring in the Pages relating to the bikes in the list. To do this, add a *reverse relationship* (Bikes <- Page). It's reverse in a sense that we're bringing in content pointing *to* our list items, instead of content pointed *by* our list items. The description of this relationship should go like:

   > **Content using field_kies_je_leasefiets** - Relate each Content with a field_kies_je_leasefiets set to the content item.

   Name this relationship "Page" administratively, so we can tell which one's which.
2. Since we now have a reference to Page content via that relationship, add a contextual filter for ID, using the *Content ID from URL* option. The key piece is to use the Page relationship on this contextual filter so that it filters by Page's ID, not by Bike's ID.

After setting this up, you should now be able to filter Bike content by Page IDs in the preview.

Comment: Man, this post was usefull. For some reason I spend a couple of hours on this simple thing and I couldn't connect the dots in the right order. This post was succesfull, allthough I almost forgot to chech the box with: 

'Configure contextual filter: Content: ID

'Relationshop': 'field_kies_je_lease_fiets (bikes linked from certain page). The tip to use a descriptive admin title here, was also usefull.

Have a great weekend, and thanks again!